# Android buttons' onClickLIstener() only works once when the Activity begins, not when returning from Fragment transaction

Tags: android, callback, fragment

Any time the main Activity is started or restarted (i.e. by pressing the home button on my action bar), all of the buttons (which reside in a fragment in this main activity) work correctly. However, if I press one of the buttons, then press the back button, the home fragment and its buttons reappears but none of the button callbacks work. The button images continue to change appearance when pressed, as always.

The callbacks are assigned in the onCreateView method of the home fragment, as follows:

```
 public class HomeFragment extends SherlockFragment {
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
     button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View arg0) {
         Log.d(TAG, "Button!");
         mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                  .replace(R.id.contFragMain, new SomeFragment())
                  .addToBackStack(null)
                  .commit();
        }    
     });
 }
```

Here is the superclass of Fragments I launch with the buttons:

```
public abstract class RouteListFragment extends SherlockFragment {
  private static final String TAG = RouteListFragment.class.getName();
  private Activity mActivity;                 // parent activity
  RouteListAdapter mAdapter;
  ListView mListViewRouteList;

  public RouteListFragment() {
    super();
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mActivity = getActivity();
  }

   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     Bundle bndl = getArguments();  // data passed should contain search term
     View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_route_list, container, false);
     mListViewRouteList = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listViewRouteList);
     addRoutesToList(); //Populates the list with data via an async DB call
     return v;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using a fragment transaction `replace()` call from within a `Fragment`? I normally do this from the `Activity`. Also, try setting your `OnClickListener` in the `onViewCreated()` method of your `Fragment`.

Comment: I dont see your homefragment returning view in oncreateView method

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be stashing the Activity reference; the Activity is probably getting recreated at some point (depends on how your flow is), but you should either reassign the reference in `onAttach (Activity activity)`, or just call `getActivity()` to get the currently Activity you're attached to.

So `mActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()...`

should instead be

`getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()...`

EDIT: Wait, maybe that's not right. What is `v` in `onCreateView()`? You're not creating any UI in this `Fragment`? You should be using `onViewCreated()` to get a reference to the views in the created hierarchy.

Comment: I've changed this for all of the buttons, but it still does not work

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about using onViewCreated, could you please clarify?

Comment: Fixed it. For some reason, in onCreateView, I was returning null.